# Where is this \n coming from in my arrays (Python)?

Tags: python, arrays, newline, word-wrap

I'm trying to create a text string for the following numpy array:

```
A = array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0.64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0])
```

I can do this easily with this line of code:

```
text = f'{A}'
```

The problem I'm having is that whenever I use this f'{}' to create a string from an array, it outputs the same array, but with a \n after some characters:

```
text
'[0.   0.   0.   0.64 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.\n 1.   0.   0.   0.  ]'
```

I'm trying to use this array in the title of a plot, so I don't want the array to be text wrapping onto a new line because it makes it confusing to read/see.

I've tried using rstrip('\n') on *text* but it doesn't remove the '\n'. Does anyone have any idea what's going on? Why is this \n popping up in the string array?

Comment: This could work `text = ' '.join(i.strip() for i in str(A))`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to declare `array()` to accomplish what you are trying to do:

```
A = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0.64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]

print(A)
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0.64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]

print(f'{A}')
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0.64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0] 

A
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0.64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

It seems like you are creating a NumPy N-dimensional array there and then converting it to a `string`, so it is printing the string representation of that array when you call `print()`. Unless you specifically need a NumPy array, you can do it just like I have above, or if you need to:

```
    from numpy import array
    A = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0.64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
    B = array(A)

    print(B)
    [0.   0.   0.   0.   0.64 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
     0.   1.   0.   0.   0.  ]

    print(f'{B}')
    [0.   0.   0.   0.   0.64 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
     0.   1.   0.   0.   0.  ]

     B
     array([0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.64, 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ,
       0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 1.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ])
```

If you absolutely have to render a NumPy array as a `string`, then you can do something like this:

```
  text = f'{A}'
  text = text.replace("\n","")
```

Or as Ramón Márquez also mentioned, you can simply increase the `printoptions` line width:

```
numpy.set_printoptions(linewidth=96)
```

Documentation on NumPy arrays: https://machinelearningmastery.com/gentle-introduction-n-dimensional-arrays-python-numpy/

Documentation on NumPy print options: https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.printoptions.html

Comment: Thanks so much for the comprehensive post, this makes more sense now

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with [the way numpy can be configured to print out arrays](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.printoptions.html).

If you set the linewidth to 96 —the length of `str(A)` without any `\n` plus 1—, it won't insert line breaks:

```
numpy.set_printoptions(linewidth=96)
```